# Bug in Fuzzy Lookup in Visual Studio SSIS

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I'm using Visual Studio Pro 2013 and want to use the Fuzzy Lookup task but there seems to be a bug that prevents the component from connecting to the reference tables.

A reference file and table is specified in the Connection tab which all seems fine but the Columns tab is also needed to create the reference links between different fields of the data however there is nothing there:

[image]

The error messages are as follows:

[image]

I've read elsewhere this was a known bug on older versions of SSIS from about 2005 - anyone know what the problem is here and how I can fix this?

I should add that the connection manager and the table seem fine as they have been used many times elsewhere in the project. I've tried recreating the data flow in a new document and even restarting my PC but this simply won't work. I should add that I've not used the Fuzzy Lookup before but have looked at several references and know that the column tab should be populated with data and not be an issue.

Many Thanks,
Kw

Comment: Your reference table looks... funny. Are you trying to use a different database, like MySQL, for your reference data?

Comment: Nope they are Access tables and a data stream from an XML source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bug, it's how the product works. From the [manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137786.aspx), it specifies the reference table must be a table in sql server. A table in Access, therefore, is unsuitable for use in the fuzzy lookup component.

> The transformation needs access to a reference data source that contains the values that are used to clean and extend the input data. The reference data source must be a table in a SQL Server database

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful.